# PSSession Access Denied Error

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I try connect to from the machine psttest01 to the machine psttest02 with PSSession and certificates as authentication. For that I used this command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName psttest02 -CertificateThumbprint 7221fc5479300189759ed18031c9c0
```

But I get an Access denied Error.

When I work with Credentials like this:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName psttest02 -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

it works fine. What did I wrong? Let me know if you need some more informations

Comment: Is the computer psttest02 set up to use certificate authentication? E.g. have you set you WinRM to listen for that certificate?

Comment: Yes, I do a `Enable-PSRemoting`.I also configured a HTTPS Listener and I mapped the client certificate of psttest01 on psttest02. And I do a `Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *` on both machines.

Comment: Is the certificate is present on both machines, in the Trusted Roots? And have you tried it without the software firewall active? Also do you get any other information other than just `Access denied `?

Comment: I turn off the firewall completly. Both certificates are in Trusted Roots on both machines. Yeah there is more but it is on German and nothing important. But here is something else at the end of the error:
`+Enter-PSSession -ComputerName psttest02 -CertificateThumbprint 7221fc54793001897...
+*******************************************************************************
    +CategoryInfo         : InvalidArgument: (psttest02:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    +FullyQualifiedErrorId: CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed`

Comment: You also need the `-UseSSL` parameter for this to work. As `Enter-PSSession` uses HTTP by default.

Comment: Still the same Error. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: When you type the following `winrm get winrm/config/service/auth` and `winrm get winrm/config/client/auth` is `Certificate = true`? If not enable them by typing `winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Certificate="true"}'`

Comment: `winrm get winrm/config/service/auth` `Cerificate=false`  `winrm get winrm/config/client/auth` `Certificate=true` How to turn it on at the first?

Comment: `winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Certificate="true"}'`

Comment: Now it works. Thanks dude :)

Comment: No problem! I have summarized the comments into an answer could you please accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you use `-UseSSL` parameter and check that the certificate is present on both machines, in the Trusted Roots.

Also check that when you type the following `winrm get winrm/config/service/auth` and `winrm get winrm/config/client/auth` is `Certificate = true`

If not enable them by typing `winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Certificate="true"}'`